# Restarting through the Start menu does not apply updates but "Restart now" button in Settings app does; what precisely is the button doing?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 Settings>Update and security

Is there any way to view precisely (command or executable) what link (text or button) in the Settings app points to? My particular interest is the Restart Now button in Settings>Update and security.  After Windows Update downloads and "installs" files for a new build a simple restart will not install the upgrade even though all files are in place (C:\$Windows.~BT).  The Restart Now button executes something more than just a restart that allows the upgrade process to begin.  I know I can just use the Restart Now button but I am curious as to what this button uses to start the upgrade process. There must be a script, executable or task associated with this button.

Under the power option button there is an option to Update and restart. Even this option will not install/upgrade Windows 10 to a new build.  I realize that installing/upgrading to a new build is different than just a routine update. But there is something special about the Restart now button in Windows update when dealing with a new build.

There are several tasks in the Task Scheduler that may play a role. They can be found under \Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator.

Comment: Restart will not apply windows updates by default but shutdown will.

Comment: I tried the Update and shutdown option when updating to build 14279 and the results are the same as described above.  On next start the new build was not installed.

Comment: @MichaelT did you find any solution on how that button works. I am looking into the exactly same issue..